# How to set a variable in Makefile without giving a value?

Tags: makefile

```
#### Makefile.header ####
ifndef Hello
  C_LINK = -switchOne
else
  C_LINK = $(Hello)
endif

#### Makefile ####
...
Hello=
...
include Makefile.header
...
```

Question> The file `Makefile` includes the file `Makefile.header`. I would like to provide an option to the user so that they can customize the `C_LINK`, disable the default `C_LINK`, or use the predefined `C_LINK`.

Case 1> Customize the switch

The user can provide a value for the `Hello` to customize the value of `C_LINK`.
For example,

```
Hello = -abc -def
```

Case 2> Use the default switch

The user can use the default value of `C_LINK` by not defining the `Hello` variable inside the Makefile.

Case 3> Disable the default switch

The user can define the variable `Hello` without value to disable the `C_LINK`. I tried to use the following method but it doesn't work.

```
Hello =
```

The compiler treats the variable `Hello` as undefined.

Question> Is there a way that I can define a variable with empty value?

Thank you

Comment: With `gnu make` do you want something like `Hello ?= -switchOne`? (only set if not already set)

Comment: @Galik, the real -switchOne has many different parameters. So I would like to do it with an elegant way.

Comment: Are you using Gnu make?

Comment: yes. gcc (GCC) 6.3.1 20170216 (Red Hat 6.3.1-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **`GNU Make`** you can use the `?=` operator like this:

```
Default_Value ?= MainDefault

Value ?= $(Default_Value)
```

Then in the included makefile you can set your options in these different ways:

```
# option #1
Value := -abc -def
```

or

```
# option #2 (do nothing)
```

or

```
#option #3 (clear default) 
Default_Value :=
```

Now `# option #1` sets Value so the Makefile will not change it.

Also `# option #2` does nothing so the Makefile will add its own default.

And `# option #3` sets the default to blank so the Makefile will add blank to `Value`.

Comment: I also found the following method works too: `ifeq ($(origin Hello), undefined)
  FOO = ....
endif` https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html